# Is there a way to view the Shadow DOM in IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, shadow-dom

Is there a way to view and edit the Shadow DOM attributes in internet explorer of an input[type="range"] element for example? My goal is to style a slider for ie11, and would like to test some things right in the browser. Just like you can do it in Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately no (as far as I know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IE11 doesn't support Shadow DOM.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom)

Better browsers (like Chrome) use something very like Shadow DOM to build every component that you see and can expose that as part of this new (and still very bleeding edge) feature.

I'm not sure on IE11, but in older versions of IE the rendering engine always used the Windows OS components for everything. I'm not sure they actually use the HTML engine to build components even now, but even if they do they'd have to enable accessing those internals.